# Can't get icon & text to appear

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I can't seem to get icon button to appear with text next to it. Should look like:

[image]

I am following the introduction tutorial in Udacity. Still trying to get my head around all of the correct formatting, widgets, etc

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: "Category List",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('This is a list item'),
        ),
        body: Category(),
      ),

    ),
  );
}

class Category extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => {},
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.access_alarms),
                Text('Click'),
              ],     

            ),
          ),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: "Category List",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('This is a list item'),
        ),
        body: Category(),
      ),

    ),
  );
}

class Category extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        decoration:BoxDecoration(
          color:Colors.green.withOpacity(0.4),
          border:Border.all(),

        ),

        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => {},
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.access_alarms),
                Text('Click'),
              ],     

            ),
          ),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to wrap your icons and text using `Expanded()` widget?